# Linq for multiple joins including an aggregate count from a joined table

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This linq query currently works but I hate using subqueries to accomplish this. I know how I would do this in straight SQL but I want to use linq.

There has to be a more optimized way using groups rather than a subquery.  Basically, this query is a list of videos and each video has a list of comments.  I just want to show the comment count for each video.

```cs
query = from x in _db.tblVideos
        //join c in _db.tblComments on x.videoId equals c.mediaId
        join y in _db.tblFavorites
        on new { userId = search.userId, videoId = x.videoId } equals new { userId = y.userId, videoId = y.mediaId }
        into jointData
        from v in jointData.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where !x.hidden && x.hls.Length > 0
        select new VideoDto
        {
            videoId = x.videoId,
            title = x.title,
            featuring = x.featuring,
            date = x.date,
            file = x.file,
            comments = _db.tblComments.Where(b => b.mediaId == x.videoId && b.mediaType == "video").Count(),
            favoriteId = v.favoriteId,
            dateAdded = x.dateAdded
        };
```

I tried the code above and I'm getting my desired results.  I just want to find a more optimized way for achiving this.

Comment: `I want to use linq` why? LINQ isn't an alternative to SQL, it's a query language over some other provider. If you use an ORM like EF Core, you're dealing with entities, not tables. In ORMs you don't need JOINs at all, it's the ORM's job to load related objects using JOINs based on entity properties. If `User` has a `Favorites` property, and `Favorite` has a `Video`, the ORM will generate the JOINs when you try to access `user.Favorites`. If you want a user's favorite videos you can write `context.Videos.Where(v=>v.Favorite.User==someUser)`

Comment: "There has to be a more optimized way using groups rather than a subquery."  - why do you think this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you can use grouping:

```cs
var commetsPerVideo =
    from c in _db.tblComments
    where c.mediaType == "video"
    group c by new { videoId = b.mediaId } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.videoId,
        Count = g.Count()
    };

query = 
    from x in _db.tblVideos
    join c in commetsPerVideo on x.videoId equals c.videoId into cgj
    from c in cgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join y in _db.tblFavorites
        on new { userId = search.userId, videoId = x.videoId } equals new { userId = y.userId, videoId = y.mediaId }
        into jointData
    from v in jointData.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where !x.hidden && x.hls.Length > 0
    select new VideoDto
    {
        videoId = x.videoId,
        title = x.title,
        featuring = x.featuring,
        date = x.date,
        file = x.file,
        comments = (int?)c.Count ?? 0,
        favoriteId = v.favoriteId,
        dateAdded = x.dateAdded
    };
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Nullable object must have a value." error.

Comment: My fault, corrected query.